# Css before and after doesn't work correctly

Tags: css

When I change before content to arabic or persian like 'ریال', the before places right of span . But I want a code that doesn't change the place of currency anyway and any language.

```css
.price-value::before {
    content: 'ریال';
}
```

```html
<span class="price-value">15.50</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the browser aligns the text as per language but you can alwasy overwrite it using css

```css
span {
  display: inline-block; /* to clear the float left/right */
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

[class*="price-value"]::before {
  float: left; /* change the value to float right if you want to align the text to right */
}

.price-value-1::before {
  content: 'ریال';
}

.price-value-2::before {
  content: '$';
}

.price-value-3::before {
  content: '£';
}
```

```html
<span class="price-value-1">15.50</span>

<span class="price-value-2">15.50</span>

<span class="price-value-3">15.50</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.price-value::before {
content: 'ریال';
float: left;
margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="price-value">15.50</span>
```

Its working fine. Please check it again. Otherwise send full code.

Comment: No, When I change the content to an Arabic or Persian word. this place change to right. Please change the content to 'ریال'.

Comment: Please put this in comment as this is NOT the solution. You have just copied the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

```
.price::after {
content: 'ریال';
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
}

<span class="price">15.50</span>
```

Try this